# Apostrophes in array from Bitbucket API

Tags: php, bitbucket

I'm processing each commit by using:

```
$author = $commit['author']['raw'];
$commitMessage = $commit['message'];
$commitMessage = trim(str_replace("\n", "", $commitMessage));
$date = str_replace('T', ' ', $commit['date']) . "\n";
$date = explode("+", $date);
$date = $date[0];

$message = $author . "\n" . $commitMessage . "\n" . $date;
```

And I get """ prepended and appended to the array, so:

```
"""
some data
"""
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to remove it?

I've tried using str_replace with different needles, also tried using strpos to see if it even is detected.
Using explode doesn't help either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it...
I was using dd() (since I was just testing the output of the array), and I switched just now by returning it as a normal array.